# Android activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, android-activity

in my application i'm open activity from service each 1 minute if in web service i have some data. now in this my code i get sometimes this below error. after search any document about this error and trace application i can find whats caused this error.

full log cat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.ServiceDialog}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
    at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
    at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:231)
    at com.example.ServiceDialog.onCreate(ServiceDialog.java:195)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
    ... 11 more
java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
    at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
    at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:231)
    at com.example.ServiceDialog.onCreate(ServiceDialog.java:195)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

my activity:

```
public class ServiceDialog extends Activity {

    private Context ctx;
    private String count;
    private Boolean ps;
    private Boolean sn;
    private String mLastID;
    private String mSmsNumber;
    private String mMobileNumber;
    private String mContactName;
    private String mSmsBody;
    private String mSenderName;
    private String mDate;
    private MediaPlayer sms_music;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
    private TextView count_sms;
    private Intent   intent;
    MyResultReceiver resultReceiver;
    private ContentResolver contentResolver;
    private boolean getCurrentActivity;
    private LinearLayout open_app;
    private TextView content;
    private TextView title;
    private TextView tv_date_time;
    private TextView tv_name_family;
    private TextView te_sms_text;
    private TextView tv_phone_number;
    private TextView title;
    private LinearLayout main_window;
    private Integer  notify = 0;
    private Integer  unread_messages = 0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        requestWindowFeature ( Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE );
        getWindow ().setFlags ( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );
        setContentView ( R.layout.service_view_dialog );

        ctx = getBaseContext ();
        G.redirect = false;
        /* Set current Activity runnable with this activity class */
        G.activity = this;

        title                 = (TextView) findViewById ( R.id.tv_title );
        content               = (TextView) findViewById ( R.id.content );
        count_sms             = (TextView) findViewById ( R.id.tv_count_new_sms );
        tv_date_time          = (TextView) findViewById ( R.id.tv_date_time );
        tv_name_family        = (TextView) findViewById ( R.id.tv_name_family );
        tv_phone_number       = (TextView) findViewById ( R.id.tv_phone_number );
        te_sms_text           = (EditText) findViewById ( R.id.te_sms_text );

        title.setText          ( ctx.getResources ().getString ( R.string.count_new_sms_received ) );

        main_window           = (LinearLayout) findViewById ( R.id.main_window );

        int count  = 0;
        int unread= 0;
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent ().getExtras ();
            if (extras == null) {
                count = 0;
            } else {
                G.config_username = extras.getString ( "username" );
                G.config_password = extras.getString ( "password" );
                unread_messages   = extras.getInt    ( "unread"   );
                notify            = extras.getInt    ( "notify"   );
                G.db              = new DatabaseHandler ( getBaseContext () );
            }
        }
        contentResolver = ctx.getContentResolver ();
        Button   send_sms              = (Button)   findViewById ( R.id.send_sms );

        open_app                       = (LinearLayout) findViewById ( R.id.open_app );
        LinearLayout delete            = (LinearLayout) findViewById ( R.id.delete );
        LinearLayout forward           = (LinearLayout) findViewById ( R.id.forward );


        ps = Configuration.getInstance ().getBoolean ( getApplication (), Configuration.SharedPrefsTypes.PLAY_SOUND );

        sn = Configuration.getInstance ().getBoolean ( getApplication (), Configuration.SharedPrefsTypes.SHOW_NOTOFICATION );
        //Log.e("Notification State is : ", sn+"");

        count_sms.setText( unread_messages +"");
        new LongOperation ().execute ( unread_messages );
        notification();


        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
        params.screenBrightness = 1.0f;
        getWindow().setAttributes(params);

        PowerManager powermanager =  ((PowerManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE));
        wakeLock=powermanager.newWakeLock(
                PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK |
                        PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TsmsScreenOn");
        wakeLock.acquire();

        resultReceiver = new MyResultReceiver(null);
        intent = new Intent(this, ToobaPayamakService.class);
        intent.putExtra("receiver", resultReceiver);
        startService(intent);
    }

    public void updateAndIntertDialog( Integer received_count){
        Cursor cursor      = G.db.getSingleRowReceivedFromDatabase( G.config_username );
        if ( cursor != null && cursor.getCount() != 0 ) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                mLastID       = cursor.getString(2);
                mSmsBody      = cursor.getString(7);
                mSenderName   = cursor.getString(5);
                mDate         = cursor.getString ( 9 );
                mSmsNumber    = cursor.getString(3);
                mContactName  = G.getContentNameFromContactList(mSenderName,contentResolver);
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(mContactName))
                    /* if contact name not exist in contact show resolve by service */
                    mContactName = mSenderName;
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        //Log.e("LAST ID FOE CHECK -------------",mLastID);
        tv_name_family.setText ( mContactName );
        tv_phone_number.setText ( mSmsNumber );
        tv_date_time.setText   ( mDate.substring(11, 16) );
        mMobileNumber = G.getContactMobile ( mContactName );
        content.setText        ( mSmsBody );

        getCurrentActivity = Configuration.getInstance ()
                .getBoolean ( getApplication (),
                        Configuration.SharedPrefsTypes.ACTIVITY_IS_RUNNING );
        Log.e("Activity is : ", getCurrentActivity+"");
        if( getCurrentActivity ){
            try{
                G.fillItems ( contentResolver );
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e ( "Fill Items in ServiceDialog", e.getMessage () );
            }
        }

        main_window.setVisibility ( View.VISIBLE );
    }

    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Integer> {
        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {  // params[0] is unread;
            int result = 0;
            try {
                if( G.checkInternetConnection () ) {
                    G.getRequestFromServer ( 0, params[ 0 ], contentResolver );
                    result =  params[0];
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace ();
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            if( result != 0 ) {
                updateAndIntertDialog( result );
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
    }

    class UpdateUI implements Runnable{
        String received_count;

        public UpdateUI(String received_count) {
            this.received_count = received_count;
        }
        public void run() {
            new LongOperation ().execute ( Integer.valueOf ( received_count ) );
        }
    }

    class MyResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver{
        public MyResultReceiver(Handler handler) {
            super(handler);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
            runOnUiThread(new UpdateUI(""+resultCode));
        }
    }

}
```

**line 195 is:**

```
protected void onPreExecute() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

initialize

```
private boolean getCurrentActivity = false;
```

Change code,

```
Log.e("Activity is : ", getCurrentActivity+"");
```

by

```
Log.e("Activity is : ", Boolean.toString(getCurrentActivity));
```

&

```
Log.e ( "Fill Items in ServiceDialog", e.getMessage () );
```

by

```
Log.e("Fill Items in ServiceDialog", "I got an error", e);
```

hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your AsyncTask syntax.

change order of asynctask

1. onPreExecute()
2. doInBackground()
3. onProgressUpdate()
4. onPostExecute()